# android grid view adapter cannot select item after image resize

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I have a layout which incorporates a gridviewadapter. The gridview layout contains single image view.

Everything works fine, I can scroll around and select an item, until I set a scale on the image view. As soon as I scale the imageview, the scrolling still works but I am unable to select an item (if I tap around the screen randomly then occasionally a change event is triggered, but it appears very random).

this is my GridViewAdapted getView code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder view;
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

        view.imgLetter = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.GridImage);


        convertView.setTag(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    view.imgLetter.setBackground(letters.get(position).getDrawable(view.imgLetter.getContext()));

    //as soon as these two lines are added, it becomes 
    //impossible to select an item in my grid view!
    view.imgLetter.setScaleX((float)0.5);
    view.imgLetter.setScaleY((float)0.5);         
    return convertView;


}
```

And here is my GridItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GridImage"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

The same behavior occurs when setting the scale in the XML file

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: ummm... I am trying to scale the image resource in the grid view to half its original size...

Answer (score 0):

In my own code I have `MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter`. If you are doing something similar, then after scaling the image try calling

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

See [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).

Comment: Yes I am extending BaseAdapter. I've tries what you're suggesting and it hasn't had any effect. I wouldn't have thought it was as I'm doing the scaling in getView(), so it should be scaled before it's rendered - ie no change is taking place in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to wrap the imageview in a LinearLayout in GridItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/GridImage"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```